# Ruby idiom for default values

Tags: ruby, idioms

Is there a better way to write this in Ruby, without writing "bar" twice?

```
foo = bar > 0 ? bar : 1
```

Comment: I can't answer my own question for 8 hours, but: foo = [bar, 1].max

Comment: Assuming it's an integer, sure, although I'm not convinced it's better.

Comment: @miku's answer is actually the more common one for Ruby.

Comment: @nick miku's answer doesn't work for 0 as he said himself, only nil and false. even if it did, it still wouldn't work as above because it would let negative numbers through.

Comment: That's a good point.  The use case isn't just a default value but is a default and a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a generic use case, but:

```
foo = [bar, 1].max
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ irb

>> x ||= "default"
=> "default"

>> x ||= "nothing changes, since x has been defined"
=> "default"
```

The value of x will be replaced with "default", but only if x is nil or false. So I am not sure it fits your use case `(x > 0)`.

`x ||= "default"` is just a shorthand for `x || x = "default"`.

Comment: Technically `x ||= "default"` is a shorthand for `x = x || "default"`, which means the same thing anyway.

Comment: @LBg: No. It's `x || x = "default"`. See http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I just ran `defined? x ||= "" #=> "assignment"`, `defined? x = x || "" #=> "assignment"` and `defined? x || x = "" #=> "expression"`. But yes, you are right, thank you.

Comment: @LBg: Interesting! I didn't expect that.